# Ubuntu Server 18.04.5 Start Job + Boot\EFI

Tags: boot, mount

I already searched and read several similar problems here, but none of them it's like mine.

I have this server with Ubuntu, it only has the ubuntu, no GUI and I just ran apt-get upgrade, installed a bunch of updates, in the end I had to reboot the system and then the system get stuck in the emergency mode.
After checking the logs and looking for the boot process, it get stuck and counting the 1m30s for the "A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-XXXX\x2dYYYY.device" until it times out.

So I checked the fstab and compare the UUID in there with the values of blkid, and everything matches. I have two hdds and the swap file, so I disabled the second HDD and the swapfile just to check if it makes any difference, let only the ext4 (mount /) and the vfat (mount /boot/efi), but that doesn't made any difference.

So what's wrong here?

The UUID is correct, in the booting log, I can confirm that's the exact same UUID, and matches the one present in the fstab.

BTW if I let the second HDD in the fstab, it fails too, don't know if it's related to the first fail...

Thanks

**edit**

The second hdd, it's another drive, formated as ntfs, that it's used for backups, and media center, so it doesn't have anything special.

The current fstab file

```bsh
UUID=23b7272a-f7ae-4e90-a8ec-de6253bbf253 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
# UUID=25545e32-6b5e-45cd-97e8-ac3823e14213 /home/jnap/STUFF     ext4    defaults        0       0
# UUID=109A-51C7  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
```

The error:

```
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-25545e32\x2d6b5e\x2d45cd\x2d97e8\x2dac3823e14213.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-25545e32\x2d6b5e\x2d45cd\x2d97e8\x2dac3823e14213.device/start timed out.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-25545e32\x2d6b5e\x2d45cd\x2d97e8\x2dac3823e14213.device.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /home/jnap/STUFF.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Job local-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: home-jnap-STUFF.mount: Job home-jnap-STUFF.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-25545e32\x2d6b5e\x2d45cd\x2d97e8\x2dac3823e14213.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-25545e32\x2d6b5e\x2d45cd\x2d97e8\x2dac3823e14213.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Starting ebtables ruleset management...
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Starting Set console font and keymap...
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Closed Syslog Socket.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Started Stop ureadahead data collection 45s after completed startup.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Reached target Login Prompts.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Starting Set console scheme...
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Reached target Paths.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Reached target Sockets.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Started Emergency Shell.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Reached target Emergency Mode.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Starting Load AppArmor profiles...
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Reached target Timers.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Started Set console scheme.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer apparmor.systemd[479]: Restarting AppArmor
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Started Set console font and keymap.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer apparmor.systemd[479]: Reloading AppArmor profiles
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Started ebtables ruleset management.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Reached target Network (Pre).
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Reached target System Time Synchronized.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd-networkd[497]: Enumeration completed
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd-timesyncd[494]: No network connectivity, watching for changes.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1628527848.796:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=493 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1628527848.796:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=493 comm="apparmor_parser
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1628527848.904:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=490 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1628527848.904:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=490 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1628527848.904:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=492 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1628527848.904:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=492 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1628527848.904:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=492 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1628527848.904:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=491 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1628527848.904:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/lxc-start" pid=502 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer kernel: r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer kernel: r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1628527848.920:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default" pid=504 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer audit[493]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=493 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer audit[493]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=493 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer audit[490]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=490 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer audit[490]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=490 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer audit[492]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=492 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer audit[492]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=492 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer audit[492]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=492 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer audit[491]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=491 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer audit[502]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/lxc-start" pid=502 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer audit[504]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default" pid=504 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer audit[504]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default-cgns" pid=504 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer audit[504]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default-with-mounting" pid=504 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer audit[504]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default-with-nesting" pid=504 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer audit[505]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=505 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Aug 09 17:50:49 AtomServer apparmor.systemd[479]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd-networkd[497]: enp3s0: IPv6 successfully enabled
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd-networkd[497]: lo: Link is not managed by us
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Starting Wait for Network to be Configured...
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd-networkd-wait-online[500]: ignoring: lo
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd-networkd-wait-online[500]: ignoring: enp3s0
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Started Wait for Network to be Configured.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd-resolved[501]: Positive Trust Anchors:
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd-resolved[501]: . IN DS 19036 8 2 49aac11d7b6f6446702e54a1607371607a1a41855200fd2ce1cdde32f24e8fb5
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd-resolved[501]: . IN DS 20326 8 2 e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd-resolved[501]: Negative trust anchors: 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-addr.arpa 18.172.in-addr.arpa 19.172.in-addr.arpa 20.172.in-addr.arpa 21.172.in-addr.arpa 22.172.in-addr.arpa 23.172.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd-resolved[501]: Using system hostname 'AtomServer'.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd-networkd[497]: enp3s0: Link UP
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Reached target Network.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
Aug 09 17:50:48 AtomServer systemd[1]: Starting Availability of block devices...
Aug 09 17:50:49 AtomServer audit[506]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lsb_release" pid=506 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:49 AtomServer systemd[1]: Started Availability of block devices.
Aug 09 17:50:49 AtomServer audit[503]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=503 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:49 AtomServer audit[503]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=503 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:49 AtomServer audit[503]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=503 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:49 AtomServer audit[503]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=503 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 09 17:50:49 AtomServer systemd[1]: Started Load AppArmor profiles.
Aug 09 17:50:49 AtomServer systemd[1]: Starting Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd...
Aug 09 17:50:49 AtomServer snapd-apparmor[509]: find: ‘/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/’: No such file or directory
Aug 09 17:50:49 AtomServer systemd[1]: Started Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd.
Aug 09 17:50:49 AtomServer systemd[1]: Startup finished in 15.426s (firmware) + 4.033s (loader) + 7.213s (kernel) + 1min 34.337s (userspace) = 2min 1.012s.
Aug 09 17:50:49 AtomServer systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 340 (plymouthd).
Aug 09 17:50:52 AtomServer systemd-networkd[497]: enp3s0: Gained carrier
Aug 09 17:50:52 AtomServer systemd-timesyncd[494]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Aug 09 17:50:52 AtomServer kernel: r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link up
Aug 09 17:50:52 AtomServer kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
Aug 09 17:50:53 AtomServer systemd-timesyncd[494]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Aug 09 17:50:53 AtomServer systemd-networkd[497]: enp3s0: Gained IPv6LL
Aug 09 17:50:53 AtomServer systemd-networkd[497]: enp3s0: Configured
Aug 09 17:50:53 AtomServer systemd-timesyncd[494]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Aug 09 17:50:53 AtomServer systemd-timesyncd[494]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Aug 09 17:51:33 AtomServer systemd[1]: Starting Stop ureadahead data collection...
Aug 09 17:51:33 AtomServer systemd[1]: Started Stop ureadahead data collection.
Aug 09 17:51:56 AtomServer sudo[523]:     root : TTY=tty1 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/vi /etc/fstab
Aug 09 17:51:56 AtomServer sudo[523]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 09 17:52:16 AtomServer sudo[523]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug 09 17:52:18 AtomServer sudo[525]:     root : TTY=tty1 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/reboot
Aug 09 17:52:18 AtomServer sudo[525]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 09 17:52:18 AtomServer systemd[1]: Stopped target Login Prompts.
Aug 09 17:52:18 AtomServer systemd[1]: Stopping Availability of block devices...
Aug 09 17:52:18 AtomServer systemd[1]: Stopped target Emergency Mode.
Aug 09 17:52:18 AtomServer systemd[1]: Stopped target User and Group Name Lookups.
Aug 09 17:52:18 AtomServer systemd[1]: Stopped target Swap.
```

Comment: You seem to have encountered a problem I've answered a few times before. I think you need to report a bug. In the meantime, you can boot the system by commenting out your `/boot/efi` line in `/etc/fstab`, by adding a `#` at the beginning of the line. This will allow your system to boot, but any upgrades to the GRUB package or configuration will fail.

Comment: Thanks, just my luck, like I said, read several posts... 
This solve the boot problem, but if I enabled the other HDD it still fails.. And it has nothing related to the boot efi grub whatever.

Comment: Could you update the article with more information on what happens with the second HDD in this case? The last few console messages, surrounded by code fences, as shown in the [Formatting Guide, Code and Preformatted Text section](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), would be helpful.